# Internal mic not working with Skype 4.0.0.8 in12.04

Tags: 12.04, skype, microphone, input

I installed Skype 4.0.0.8 in my Lubuntu 12.04. The internal mic is not working, while the external mic is. At the same time, other recording software (like gnome sound recorder, audacity or guvcview) are working ok with both inputs (internal and external).

Do you have any idea why this can be?

In the Skype configuration, '**allowing Skype to manage my volume control**' is unchecked. If I check it, Skype turns mic and boost volume to the maximum, but it's not good (a lot of cracks and my voice on the background almost inaudible).

Answer (score 1):

It's solved. The problem was with pulseaudio, so i made an script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
killall pulseaudio
skype
```

to kill pulseaudio before invoking skype. I also had to create a file ~/.pulse/client.conf with the following line:

```
autospawn=no
```

to avoid pulseaudio to restart automatically when i invoke the kill command.

cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution that doesn't involve killing pulseaudio. You have to unlink the input channels, turn left channel totally down, and regulate input volume just with right channel.